# C# ASP.NET MVC 5 problems using an Entity Framework 6 DbContext from another project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm experiencing a very strange problem, hopefully someone can help. I've got a Visual Studio solution with several projects in it, 2 of these are standalone MVC projects using EF6.

Now in one of the projects (project A) I would like to access some of the models from the other project (project B), I figure its either that or recreate the models again in project A. Instead of this I thought it would make sense to add a reference to project B and then create an instance of the 'remote' context from project B.

However, this is where things get strange - project A is working fine but on the index page in project A the table which should have records listsed comes up ok but with 0 results?!? No errors, just no records...

So my code in the Index action in project A is a bit like:-

```
public ActionResult Index()
{        
    var ctx = new ContextFromProjectB();
    IQueryable<MyModelType> models = ctx.MyModels.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == 0);

    return View(models);
}
```

I've put a breakpoint on the 'return View();' line to check the properties out and the problem is that 'models' is always empty, so 'Count' property is 0. There are definitely records in there. However, if I change the code to this...

```
public ActionResult Index()
{        
    var ctx = new ContextFromProjectB();

    return View();
}
```

And keep the breakpoint on the 'return View();' line and examine the 'ctx' variable I can browse to the DbSet in question and it enumarates the results and I can see the records!?! Eh?

Can anyone see why it would do this? How can I get my records? Help please! :-)

Comment: Try change the code to this `IQueryable<MyModelType> models = ctx.MyModels.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == 0).ToList();`. Check also with Sql Profiler to see the actual query EF is performing

Comment: Did you modify your Project A configuration for the Project B `DbContext`? Actually, I would suggest moving your model classes to a separate class library project and reference them in each project specific `DbContext`. Avoids duplicate models and keeps the dependencies relatively clean.

Comment: .ToList() worked but I also had to add the ContextFromProjectB connection string to project A's web.config. Thanks Martin I've 'uppped' your comment